# How can I access sound samples from a audio file in a iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, dynamic

I have developed a dynamic sound compressor (which is already implemented in Matlab and Windows), and I want to create a simple iPhone app that just accesses the music library and applies the filter to the track, and for that I would need in some way to have access to the sound samples of that file, to apply the gain that the compressor will calculate. It won't change the original file, it will just play the new calculated sound samples. How can I do that using iOS sound libraries?

Answer (score 0):

MTAudioProcessingTap is the best option for this task. This is a good starting point:

http://chritto.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/processing-avplayers-audio-with-mtaudioprocessingtap/

If you want something that works for lower iOS versions, here is a sample:

https://github.com/iitotoro/BufferedAudioPlayer

Hope this helps, feel free to ask if you have more questions.